# JQuery ajax call with django session

Tags: ajax, django, session, authentication

I have a site that uses custom authentication in Django that authenticates to a web service using a username, password, and domain.  I need to store this information for every subsequent view's request object.

All seems to be going well until I try to make a jquery $.ajax call, debugging the view that gets called from the ajax request I have no session information and the user is AnonymousUser.

I need the session variables to make subsequent calls to the web service for data to display.  I've tried a few things in there but nothing seems to work correctly.  I want to make sure users a logged in before being able to submit these web service queries as I want to keep the username/domain to lookup the password (and not have it on the client side) in the view and ensure the user is always logged in.

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if settings.DEBUG == True:
        print "views.login:Attempting loging at views.login(request)"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if settings.DEBUG:
            print "views.login: method is POST"

        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if settings.DEBUG:
                print "Form is valid, attepmting to authenticate"
            Login(request, form.get_user())
            str = reverse('cm_base.views.index')
            request.session['username']=form.get_user()
            request.session['domain']=form.get_domain()

            return render_to_response('cm_base/index.html', 
                              {"DEBUG": True,
                               "user":request.session.get('username'),
                               'tabs': settings.TAB_LIST},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
                # Their password / email combination must have been incorrect
            pass

    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render_to_response('cm_base/login.html', 
                              {"DEBUG": True,
                               'form' : form
                               },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required()
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "POSTING"
    if settings.DEBUG == True:

        print "views.index:Opening index"

    return render_to_response('cm_base/index.html', 
                              {"DEBUG": True,
                               "user":"user",
                               'tabs': settings.TAB_LIST},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required()
def scorecard(request):
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.session.get('username'),
                                  domain=request.session.get('domain'))
```

*fails on the above line with DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'username': None, 'domain': None}

base.js

```
$.ajax({
    url : path,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken':getCookie('csrftoken')
        ,'sessionid':getCookie('sessionid')
        },
    success : function(data) {
        console.log($(this));
        //refresh right div
        $('#contentpane').empty();
        $('#contentpane').html(data.rhtml);
        console.log(data.rhtml);
    }
});
```

Comment: a) what is the content of `request.POST`? are you sure that you are encoding the correct data in your js - what is $(this) bound to? What is the content of `$(this).serialize()`? Web dev tools (Firebug or Google Chrome dev tools) should be able to show you the request and response data

Comment: request.POST/.GET are both empty dictionaries (argv in the post in firebug is undefined).  Cookies only has the csrftoken and session is an empty dictionary, along with the request.user being AnonymouseUser.  I feel like I'm either not persisting the request object to the ajax request or something very similar.  The $(this).serialize() was something I saw in other code and I had hoped it would serialize the response... however... that was an assumption and obviously not the case.

Comment: ah. you probably should do some more research on how to write an AJAX login form. Basically you need to get `username` and `password` from the form and into the `data` paramater of the `ajax` call. `$(this).serialize()` would do this for you if the `ajax` call was bound to the form `onSubmit` in the right manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my implementation of the backend that was the problem.

backends.py

```
class CustomBackend(object)
...
def get_user(self, username):
    try:
        return CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

This is called during session passing and actually uses a the primary key which is a userid, not username so this was always returning no user and defaulting to anonymous user.  I misinterpreted when the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) says the userid can be anything, including username, I thought I could pass that in as such but I have both an auto generated userid as well as a username on the object.

Comment: Thank you! I had exactly the same issue.